# Rails 3.2 including vendor 3rd party javascripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, vendor

I have a file called `hammer.js` within my vendor folder i would like to keep my 3rd party js in `vendor/assets/javascripts` and all home made stuff in `app/assets/javascripts`.

But when precompiling my assets rails won't fetch my assets from vendor. within my manifest file i have specified `//= require vendor` that didn't work so i tried `//= require hammer` and i tried `//= require hammer.js` from what i read these solutions seemed to work for some other people. But its not loading it at all

Note: I do `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` each time and the check public assets and i render the page and look at the loaded resources each time i try alternative.

**EDIT**:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts
//= require_tree .
```

so i tried this. but its still not loading

within the config/environments/production.rb i have the following

```
# Code is not reloaded between requests
config.cache_classes = true

# Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = false

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true
```

sorry this would be the first time i have set up js in rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try loading them as follows (note the path):

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts
```

Comment: is there no way to maybe reference a manifest within vendor and then simple referencing that. and why do you need to `../../../` before getting to the app dir? sorry this might be a stupid question. just want to try understand the computer science behind it?

Comment: I haven't tried multiple manifest and am not aware of it, but will certainly look into it.  For the second part I guess the reason for `../../../` is the manifest is in `app/assets/javascripts`, so three levels up.

Comment: @TheLegend, to confirm, multiple manifests is possible.  So yes, you could create a manifest in `vendor/assets/javascripts` and reference that using `//= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/my_manifest`

Answer (score 1):

If you want `hammer.js` to be precompiled as a separated file, you should change `config.assets.precompile` in `config/environments/production.rb`, I guess.

Like `config.assets.precompile += %w{ hammer.js }`, and you will see `public/assets/hammer.js`.

Comment: i have 'config.assets.compile = false' changing it to the previous way. why would they have the asset pipeline ignore the vendor assets by default now?